# How do I structure my blog engine's database for multiple post types like Tumblr?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I'm building a blog engine that has multiple post types, e.g.: text, image, link, quote.

The way I see it, I have two options:

**Option 1: A single Posts table with all columns, some of which will inevitably be NULL**

```
Post table
==========
* post_id
* created_at
* updated_at
* user_id
* post_type
* text
* image_url
* link_url
* quote_source
```

**Option 2: Separate tables for each post type**

```
Post table
==========
* post_id
* created_at
* updated_at
* user_id
* post_type

Text table
==========
* post_id
* text

Image table
===========
* post_id
* image_url
```

I think you get the hint.  What are the pros/cons of each approach?

Does anyone know what Tumblr does?  (It's not clear from their API docs.)

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using multiple tables for like entities (in this case "Posts"). I have no idea how Tumblr itself does it, but it's most likely more similar to your first post, with some fields NULL in each row, and their executable code evaluates the post_type value to determine how to handle it.

Multiple tables would quickly become a nightmare as you're pulling data from several tables to handle "one" request. For example, if you wanted to SELECT all the posts, of all types, in the last week, you'd have to SELECT from each table and merge the results (either in some sort of SQL temp table, or programmatically in your script/executable code). And that's just for a simple thing. Imagine searching, etc.

Again, I don't know how Tumblr does it, nor is their a "right" way - but the efficient way is one table.